I tried installing AppImageLauncher, getting this since trying to add PPA to my system
this is the error I get in app-get update
Hit:1 http:// download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/easyrpg/xUbuntu_23.10  InRelease
Hit:2 http:// pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Hit:3 http:// pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http:// pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 https:// repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                       
Hit:6 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease               
Err:1 http:// download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/easyrpg/xUbuntu_23.10  InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74F3DB4B6A4E28F0
Hit:7 https:// dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease          
Ign:8 https:// ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:9 https:// ppa.launchpadcontent.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:10 https:// ppa.launchpadcontent.net/irie/blender/ubuntu noble InRelease
Err:11 https:// ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ***]
Err:12 https:// ppa.launchpadcontent.net/irie/blender/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ***]
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http:// download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/easyrpg/xUbuntu_23.10  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 74F3DB4B6A4E28F0
E: The repository 'https:// ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/irie/blender/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https:// ppa.launchpadcontent.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key 22C4850146603F3DB0ED00479DA4BD18B9A06DE3 uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)


Do note your provided paste contains multiple different errors; one is for an EOL or off-topic release, where once a release goes EOL (23.10 went EOL months ago) mirrors and repositories are free to drop support for that release without further notice (EOL notices being the notice) so extra checks are required; though that URL just looks invalid thus issue does sorta match the dup anyway.

@guiverc the actual Ubuntu repos are Noble though, they just have a 23.10 repo from OpenSuse of EasyRPG in there.  That's not the core problem, though, with OP's question about the AppImageLauncher PPA, making this NOT about an EOL release.  (the PPA simply does not work anymore so while you're right with the similar link, it's still a slightly different issue with an alternative fix.)

Since 22.04 and 2022, the PPA for AppImageLauncher has not been built or build-attempted for over 365 days.  The upstream developer says to use the "continuous build" version of the upstream GitHub repository, which publishes (though it hasn't in a while) .deb files for installation of AppImageLauncher.  This .deb installs and works in Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 24.04.
Unfortunately the PPA just simply doesn't work and since the upstream developer has abandoned actual versioned releases, there's no alternative but to install from the .deb from 2022 on the GitHub repository's releases.
Note though that your mileage may vary with the usage of App Image Launcher, if there's any flaws in the code you will have to go right to the developer to get support and there is no alternative way to get updates or fixes for the package.
